# URL doesn't work with slash after removing extension using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been working on localhost, and my htaccess file is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

after adding the htacces code,the url

```
localhost/movies/news.php
```

works

```
localhost/movies/news
```

also works but

```
localhost/movies/news/
```

doesn't work. It shows "Internal Server Error".How to make it work with slash and without slash.

Comment: Hint: `RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Internally forwards movies/news/ to movies/news.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you add the slash you have `news/.php` and this is not working.

A better solution is to rewrite to a GET variable something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Then you can filter the GET variable in your script and include the file or content you need.

Comment: This works but how to use for all my pages ? I have 27pages ,writing 27 rewriterules is necessary? I have tried with $1.php?url=$1[L] which not works

Comment: Perhaps you should thinkg about a better strukture of your projekt. Don't write 27 pages. Use one php file to generate your sites. Its much easier.